# Using RX JS to make a pause between functions

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a number (about 10 or so) of requests to the API and that API has a limitation of 1 request per second. I'd like to use RX JS to make a pause after each function. My code looks something like this:

```
const source = interval(1000);
const getData = async() => { 
    let info = {
        date: new Date(),
        id: initialId,
    };
    if (fetchInitialResponse(initialId) ) { //external function that checks whether entry exists
       info['Names'] = await fetchResponse( getUrl(ADDRESSOTHERNAMES), process.env.OTHERNAMESFOUND);
       info['Address'] = await fetchResponse( getUrl(ADDRESSADDRESS), process.env.ADDRESSFOUND);
       info['Individuals'] = await fetchResponse( getUrl(ADDRESSINDIVIDUALS), process.env.INDIVIDUALSFOUND);
       //and so on with about 10 functions
        mongoConnect(true, info) //external function that writes the recieved info to mongodb 
    }
} 

const subscribe = source.subscribe( () => getData() );
```

How can I make a pause after each 'await fetchResponse' function?

Answer (score 0):

This should space out your calls by 1 second *(using zip)* and then build the responses into an info object for you *(using reduce)*.

```ts
const initialId = 1234; // Or whatever

const data$ = of({
  date: new Date(),
  id: initialId
}).pipe(
  filter(({id}) => fetchInitialResponse(id)),

  switchMap(info => {
    const apiCalls = [

      from(fetchResponse( 
        getUrl(ADDRESSOTHERNAMES), 
        process.env.OTHERNAMESFOUND
      )).pipe(
        map(names => ({...info, names}))
      ),

      from(fetchResponse( 
        getUrl(ADDRESSADDRESS), 
        process.env.ADDRESSFOUND
      )).pipe(
        map(address => ({...info, address}))
      ),

      from(fetchResponse( 
        getUrl(ADDRESSINDIVIDUALS), 
        process.env.INDIVIDUALSFOUND
      )).pipe(
        map(individuals => ({...info, individuals}))
      ),

      //and so on with about 10 functions
    ];

    return zip(interval(1000), apiCalls);
  }),

  reduce(Object.assign)

).subscribe(info => mongoConnect(true, info));
```